When using FCM, how my server can determine that a given client does not exist anymore
So, my backend server collects the per device / app Firebase token ID. But how can it know that a device was reinitialized, the app was uninstalled and reinstalled, etc. In other words, how to determine when the token ID is not valid anymore.
Looking the Python it looks as though the messaging.UnregisteredError exception would be fired when a token ID is deemed not existing anymore. But is reliable? And more importantly, how to test? (I am sure uninstalling the app will not clear the FCM service immediately...

You might want to review the documentation: "when FCM attempts to deliver a message to the device and the app was uninstalled, FCM discards that message right away and invalidates the registration token. Future attempts to send a message to that device results in a NotRegistered error." FCM doesn't know right away when an app was installed.  You have to keep sending it messages to get this information.

Getting an UnregisteredError from the FCM server is a reliable way to know that the token is no longer known within that project. When you get this response, you can safely remove it from your own database too - as sending to it will not deliver a message to a device anymore.
For a good example of how to use the response from FCM to clean up your own token database, have a look at this code. While it's written in Node.js, the same logic can be written in Pyton too.
